# Cannot add a class to h2 tag

Tags: pages, html

I'm creating a page on my Wordpress website with a series of headings and images on alternating sides of the page for each heading so I need to add `clear: left` and `clear:right` to the `h2` tags on the page. However, whenever I try to add an inline style or even a class to the h2 tag, Wordpress seems to remove it.

Am I missing something or is this a standard problem, hopefully with a standard solution?